# SQL Server stored procedure leaves columns blank

Tags: sql-server-2012, excel-2016

I have a view and a stored procedure that return the exact same data in SQL Server the only difference being the stored procedure has a parameter.

I need to connect to the stored procedure from Excel, but it fails to return data in a couple of columns. I connected to the view and the same columns are filled with data.

I want to use the stored procedure so I can use the parameter. Any idea why this is happening and what I can do about it?

I'm using Excel 2016 and MS Query with `{call dbo.storedprocedure (?)}`. The view is also be accessed through MS Query.

Comment: what are you using as the parameter? If you are passing in a value in the parameter, i would expect this to limit the result set where the view would return all rows. Can you post the stored parameter code please

Comment: it is not a question of the number of rows returned.  I want fewer rows, hence the parameter.  I only want the data for the selected project in the spreadsheet.  The problem is the columns that have no data.

Comment: Post the code please

Comment: For view and procedure in SQL and view in Excel I get.
Company ProjectID ProjectCode ProjectDesc .. PhaseID PhaseDesc ...................... JobNum ....... PartDescription
BI .... 17037 ... SLA ....... Silicon Labs . 000 ... Parent ......................... 17037-000-00 . Parent
BI .... 17037 ... SLA ....... Silicon Labs . 001 ... Grge E Lobby WD Paneling, door . 17037-001-01 . Lobby B1.114 Walnut panels
BI .... 17037 ... SLA ....... Silicon Labs . 002 ... Grge E Lobby Lacq Boxes ........ 17037-002-01 . Lobby B1.114 Lacq Ceiling Boxes

Comment: For the procedure in Excel it get
Company ProjectID ProjectCode ProjectDesc .. PhaseID PhaseDesc ...................... JobNum ....... PartDescription
BI .... 17037 ... ___ ....... Silicon Labs . 000 ... Parent ......................... 17037-000-00
BI .... 17037 ... ___ ....... Silicon Labs . 001 ... Grge E Lobby WD Paneling, door . 17037-001-01
BI .... 17037 ... ___ ....... Silicon Labs . 002 ... Grge E Lobby Lacq Boxes ........ 17037-002-01
Note that the ProjectCode is blank (___) as is the PartDescription

Comment: ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[BIspExcelTest]
    @ProjectID                   NVARCHAR(25)
AS
SELECT Project.ProjectID,
       Calcs1.ProjectCode,
       JobHead.JobNum,
       JobHead.PartDescription
  FROM Erp.Project AS Project
1st half
 INNER JOIN Erp.JobHead AS JobHead
    ON Project.Company = JobHead.Company
   AND Project.ProjectID = JobHead.ProjectID

Comment: CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('[',Project.CommentText) > 0
                          THEN SUBSTRING(Project.CommentText,
                                        CHARINDEX('[',Project.CommentText)+1,
                                        CHARINDEX(']',Project.CommentText)-CHARINDEX('[',Project.CommentText)-1)
                          ELSE COALESCE(Project.ProjectID,'')
                     END AS ProjectCode
             ) Calcs1
 WHERE Project.Company = 'BI'
   AND Project.ProjectID = @ProjectID
   AND RIGHT(JobHead.JobNum,3) IN ('-00','-01')

Comment: That is not the original code but part of it with the same result.

Comment: I got it.  The PartDescription field is defined as NVARCHAR(MAX)  I cast it as NVARCHAR(255) and it now displays.  the ProjectCode is a calculated field so I will cast it also.

Answer (score 0):

Below post suggests that MS Query ignore certain values in case of mixed data type values within same column.

[microsoft query from excel file returns empty cells while source file has data in the cells](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/microsoft-query-from-excel-file-returns-empty/ef632a32-a79f-4515-a2d5-bfda74dc6c35)